# Exposing existing Service Layer using ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I currently have a layered architecture that is as follows:

1. Service Layer - This is the main interaction point with the domain.
   Contains all the business rules, validation, etc.
2. Data/Repository Layer - This is the layer that handles all persistence of the data. Contains no    business logic or validation. Contains basically `Repository<T>`, `UnitOfWork` (EF Specific) and all the EF things like `DbContext`, `EntityTypeConfiguration`'s, etc.
3. Entity Framework
4. SQL Server

I am using an Anemic Domain Model, so basic POCO's that represent the problem domain.

I have a couple questions about exposing this via `ASP.NET WebApi`.

1. Where does the security live at? Basically things like does a user have the access to edit a record, or type of record. Can a user perform a specific action, etc. As well as things like Authentication/Role Based Authorization.
2. Should I use the WebApi as the actual service layer, or use it to expose my existing service layer over HTTP in a RESTful manner?
3. Given a basic example of say changing a name of a category, where do I enforce that the current user has authority to change said record? Do I rely on the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to get the `Identity` to check for a given role, and set that in the WebApi? Mvc Application?

Are there any good examples out there that show this type of situation I am talking about?

BTW - I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 to serve up the shell of the application (SPA) and then the front-end is going to be all AngularJS.

Comment: Please note that if you are going to use Angularjs and WebApi you don't need ASP.NET MVC5

Comment: @Dalorzo - We are using ASP.NET MVC to serve the shell of the app, and provide a templating controller... Also using Cassette for bundling/minification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question about the level of security your services should have the correct answer is what I believe it should be a principle in all applications:

> *Services should have enough security to protect the data from unwanted users*.

Once you create a service and make it public you are exposed to possible attacks of course having complex security rules may increase development time and some situations may create a decrease in performance; measure the level of the threat and plan your security accordingly.

WebApi was created with intention to provide services through Http/Rest all the principles and features build-in were made with that intention so regarding your second question and like you inferred at the end of it it is a service layer but an Http/Rest service layer.

WebApi uses an attribute `Authorize` to enforce security an as it is normally with .NET Frameworks you can inherit from it and extend it. You can learn more about it [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api).

And since you are using Angularjs and even though you will need MVC5 to use WebApi my recommendation is that you do not use MVC razor or any other server technology to render your pages.